# Como fazer overload do operador atribuição numa class que contem vector?

Tags: c++, classes, operadores, vector

Gostaria de fazer o overload do operador atribuição (`operator=`), sei que tenho que reservar memória, e copiar dados de um para o outro, no entanto não sei como copiar um vector para o outro sem saber o tamanho do mesmo.

```
    class Perfil{
    private:
       char letra; 
       vector <Carateristica*> carateristicas;
    }

    Perfil & Perfil::operator=(const Perfil & p1)
    {
        letra = p1.getLetra();

         // Agora deveria reservar memoria utilizando o new
             // e copiar os dados de um vector para o outro
    (..) 
}
```

Comment: O operador '=' retorna uma copia do vector ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o comando `for`para percorrer um vetor, e você pode usar o método `push_back` para acrescentar elementos a um vetor.

No exemplo abaixo, as funções `copy_from` e `release_old` precisam ser implementadas e dependem do tipo `Caracteristica`, que não foi mostrado.

Na verdade não é possível dar uma resposta precisa porque também a classe Perfil não está completa, faltando por exemplo o construtor e o destrutor.

```
class Perfil
{
   private:
      char letra; 
      vector<Carateristica*> carateristicas;
      char getLetra() { return letra; }

   public:
      Perfil& operator=(const Perfil&);
}

Perfil& Perfil::operator= (const Perfil& p1)
{
    for (auto c: caracteristicas)
    {
       release_old(c); // TODO: implementar 'release_old'
    }
    caracteristicas.clear(); // remove conteudo atual do vetor

    letra = p1.getLetra();
    for (auto c: p1.caracteristicas)
    {
       Caracteristica* new_c(copy_from(c)); // TODO: implementar 'copy_from'
       caracteristicas.push_back(new_c);
    }
    return *this;
}
```